# How to determine maximum texture memory on Android OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm writing a mixed 2D/3D game on Android and I'm not able to determine how much texture memory I can use. Is there any way to determine maximum texture memory in OpenGL ES?

I have my own texture cache and want to know the maximum threshold of texture memory. I'm making an approximate estimation using `activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi)`, but on some devices when I try to allocate texture (and many more are already in memory) the application crashes (`EGL_BAD_ALLOC`). When I set this threshold to a lower value, everything seems to be ok. Does anyone have any idea? Or eventually how to determine that the texture allocation was unsuccessful, instead of crashing.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you are trying to know the amout of VRAM (video RAM) available.
[The question has already been partially answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154632/android-vram-check)

However, the amount of VRAM does not determine how much textures will fit in it: these ones can be compressed, the amount of VRAM can change because of another app, and we don't know how much memory the video driver uses.

**Method 1**

[From this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8573543/1616310), you can get the maximum amount of texture units; that means the max number that can be bound at the same time:

```
int[] maxSize = new int[1];
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxSize, 0);
```

[And from this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13392835/1616310), you can retrieve the max texture size:

```
int[] maxNum = new int[1];
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, maxNum, 0);
```

So, logically, you can at least fit `maxSize[0]`²×`maxNum[0]` pixels in the VRAM without problems. Even if the VRAM runs out of space, the graphics driver will manage it for us (which *may* include an application crash in case of starvation).

Anyway, you're probably not going to adjust your textures' size depending on the VRAM amount or the available pixels; it's possible but not profitable, portable and is hard to implement properly.
There's a *way* better way to do this:

**Method 2**

99% of the time, the amout of VRAM on the graphics chip is proportional to the screen size. Thus, [use the screen's DPI (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi)](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to determine which version (size) of the texture to load (experiment with different (real) devices), so you're safe about the "will it fit for that device?".